It’s a simple intuition, but difficult to put it in a formula.
Can the following proposition be justified? If can, please show it to me. I understand the following term ’become small’ is not mathematically correct, but I am now facing another theorem that needs this following concept.In the conclusion part, the symbol $\leq$, not $<$, is especially important. Thank you!
Proposition. Let $A$ be a positive real number which is less than $\epsilon$. $(0<A<\epsilon)$. When $\delta$ becomes small, $A + \delta \le \epsilon$ is valid.

$A<\epsilon$ is equivalent to $\epsilon - A > 0$. Denote $\epsilon - A = c > 0$.
We will show that $A+\delta \le \epsilon$ is valid whenever $\delta \le c$. This is because, assuming $\delta \le c$, we have
$\begin{align}
A + \delta &\le A+c \\
&= A + (\epsilon - A) \\
&= \epsilon,
\end{align}$
hence we have $A + \delta \le \epsilon$, as desired.
Therefore, for sufficiently small $\delta>0$ (in particular, for $0 \le \delta \le \epsilon - A$), we have that $A+\delta\le\epsilon$ is valid. $\blacksquare$
